# Why radiobutton in another row is clicked too when i click radiobutton in first row?

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have 3 radiobutton in `listview`, when i click radiobutton on first line, one other `radiobutton` also come clicked when i scroll down listview.

How to solve it?

**Radiobutton clicked in first row**

[image: Radiobutton clicked in first row]

**Another row is clicked too**

[image: another row is clicked too]

> **Here is my adapter code**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.item_listview, null);
        holder.tvAlat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_alat);

        holder.tvpengecekan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pengecekan);

        holder.tvnormal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_normal);

        convertView.setTag(mPengecekanList.get(position).getId_pengecekan());
        holder.baik = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.B);
        holder.rusakringan = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RR);
        holder.rusakberat = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RB);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tvAlat.setText(mPengecekanList.get(position).getNama_alat());
    holder.tvpengecekan.setText(mPengecekanList.get(position).getPengecekan());
    holder.tvnormal.setText(mPengecekanList.get(position).getNormal());

    holder.baik.setTag(position);
    holder.rusakringan.setTag(position);
    holder.rusakberat.setTag(position);

    holder.baik.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              selectedAnswers.set(position, "1");
                 }});

holder.rusakringan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              selectedAnswers.set(position, "2");
                 }});
holder.rusakberat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              selectedAnswers.set(position, "3");
                 }});}
```

Comment: This happen because of recycle behaviour. inside getView you have to specify the default selected redio button. I think you keep selected answer list in array and of the selected is not specified in the list set the default radio check to first radio

Answer (score 0):

i can't see any problem in your code

> but definitely if you select unique id for something the other id will
>   not selected

so try to debug your code and you will find that the radio that selected with the other take the same id or the same tag some how